# Dropdown menu change opening direction right to left dynamic depended browser width

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm building a recursive menu bar. It has multiple  ul li ul li ul li.
Menu elements opening position is left to right.

But if browser width small then my opened menu items; then menu items goes to out of to right screen.

I want if browser width smaller then my opened menu items, then menu items opening direction change to right to left.

I try to building that jQuery codes but does not work properly.

My Issues are:

- If browser width smaller than the menu menu directions changed but have some bugs,
- If browser resized bigger than menu, menu width not going to 100%, need refresh browser!

  $(document).ready(function() {

  ```
  $(".anamenu li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault;
      if ($('ul', this).length) {
          var elm = $('ul:last', this);
          var off = elm.offset();
          var l = off.left;
          var w = elm.width();
          var docH = $(".disgovde").height();
          var docW = $(".disgovde").width();

          var isEntirelyVisible = (l + w <= docW);

          if (!isEntirelyVisible) {

              $("ul.anamenu li ul ul > li ul").css({
                  "left": "auto",
                  "right": "100%",
              });

              $("ul.anamenu li ul").css({
                  "left": "auto",
                  "right": "0",
              });
              $("ul.anamenu li > ul ul").css({
                  "left": "200px",
                  "right": "0",
              });
              $("ul.anamenu > li ul ul").css({
                  "left": "auto",
                  "right": "100%",
              });

          } else {
              $("ul.anamenu  li ul ul > li ul").css({
                  "left": "200px",
                  "right": "0",
              });


          }
      }
  });
  ```

  });

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".anamenu li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault;
            if ($('ul', this).length) {
                var elm = $('ul:last', this);
                var off = elm.offset();
                var l = off.left;
                var w = elm.width();
                var docH = $(".disgovde").height();
                var docW = $(".disgovde").width();

                var isEntirelyVisible = (l + w <= docW);
                if (!isEntirelyVisible) {
                    $("ul.anamenu li ul ul> li ul").css({
                        "left": "auto",
                        "right": "100%",
                    });

                    $("ul.anamenu li ul").css({
                        "left": "auto",
                        "right": "0",
                    });
                    $("ul.anamenu li > ul ul").css({
                        "left": "200px",
                        "right": "0",
                    });
                    $("ul.anamenu > li ul ul").css({
                        "left": "auto",
                        "right": "100%",
                    });

                } else {
                    $("ul.anamenu li ul ul > li ul").css({
                        "left": "200px",
                        "right": "0",
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    });




<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}


a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    /*
    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    */
}
.disgovde {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .icgovde {
        max-width: 1110px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .ustmenu {
        height: 155px;
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    }
    .ustmenu ol, .ustmenu ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .ustlogo img {
        /*width: 100%;*/
        /*margin-top: 50px;*/
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .ustlogo img:hover {
        /*width: 100%;*/
        /*margin-top: 50px;*/
        opacity: .5;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .ustsag {
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    }

    .menu {
        /*height: 45px;*/
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin-top: 15px;
        background: #fff;
    }

    ul.anamenu {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 35px;
    }

    ul.anamenu > li {
        /*padding: 10px;*/
        float: left;
        height: 45px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        width: max-content;
    }

    ul.anamenu > li > a {
        display: block;
        font-family: manualeregular;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #0099cc;
        padding: 0 15px;
        line-height: 35px;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);

    }

    ul.anamenu > li:hover > a {
        background-color: #0099cc;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;

    }

    ul.anamenu ul {
        background: #0099cc;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 35px;
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 250ms all;
        -webkit-transition: 250ms all;
        -moz-transition: 250ms all;
        -ms-transition: 250ms all;
        -o-transition: 250ms all;
        visibility: hidden;

    }


    ul.anamenu ul li {
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed40;

    }

    ul.anamenu ul li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;

    }


    ul.anamenu ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 12px 12px;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: manualeregular;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);


    }

    ul.anamenu > li ul ul {
        top: 0;
        left: 180px;
        background: #0099cc;

    }

    /*


    ul.anamenu > li ul:last-child ul ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 100%;
    }
*/
    ul.anamenu > li:hover > ul {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        top: 35px;

    }

    ul.anamenu ul li:hover > ul {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        left: 200px;
        z-index: 1;

    }

    ul.anamenu ul li ul li:hover {
        background-color: #ededed;

    }

    ul.anamenu ul li:hover {
        background-color: #ededed;

    }

    ul.anamenu ul li > ul li:hover > a {
        color: #0099cc;

    }

    ul.anamenu ul li:hover > a {
        color: #0099cc;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="disgovde">

    <div class="icgovde">
        <div class="ustmenu">
         <div class="ustsag">
                <div class="menu" style="display: flex;">
                    <ul class="anamenu">
                        <li><a href="index.php">ANASAYFA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="hakkimizda/hakkimizda-1">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="kategori/urunlerimiz"><span class="asagiok"></span>ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</a>
                            <ul class="altmenu">
                                <li><a href="kategori/genel-celik"><span class="sagok"></span>Genel Çelik</a>
                                    <ul class="altmenu">
                                        <li><a href="kategori/imalat-celigi"><span class="sagok"></span>İmalat Çeliği</a>
                                            <ul class="altmenu" style="left: 200px; right: 0px;">
                                                <li><a href="detay/1040">1040</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="hizmetler/hizmetler">HİZMETLER</a></li>
                        <li><a href="referanslar/bayilikler">BAYİLİKLER</a></li>
                        <li><a href="galeri/galeri">GALERİ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="iletisim/iletisim">İLETİŞİM</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cizgi"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to style differently based on screen width.

Following mobile first principles, style the dropdown to open vertically then below that in your css setup a media query like this.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .anamenu ul {
    // Modify dropdown styling to open horizontally.
  }
}
```

Comment: I ask another thing

Comment: @doli I see! You're talking about nesting menus. So far you have them opening to the right, and if it goes past the window it sticks to the right edge. You just can't get the next one to open to the left?